# How to create a bag of words from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataframe

```
    CATEGORY    BRAND
0   Noodle  Anak Mas
1   Noodle  Anak Mas
2   Noodle  Indomie
3   Noodle  Indomie
4   Noodle  Indomie
23  Noodle  Indomie
24  Noodle  Mi Telor Cap 3
25  Noodle  Mi Telor Cap 3
26  Noodle  Pop Mie
27  Noodle  Pop Mie
...
```

I already make sure that df type is string, my code is

```
df = data[['CATEGORY', 'BRAND']].astype(str)
import collections, re
texts = df
bagsofwords = [ collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', txt))
            for txt in texts]
sumbags = sum(bagsofwords, collections.Counter())
```

When I call

```
sumbags
```

The output is

```
 Counter({'BRAND': 1, 'CATEGORY': 1})
```

I want all of the data count in sumbags, except the title, to make it clear something like

```
Counter({'Noodle': 10, 'Indomie': 4, 'Anak': 2, ....}) # because it is bag of words
```

I need every 1 word counts

Comment: `Counter({'Noodle': 9, 'Indomie': 4, .....})`

Comment: I need 1 word counts

Comment: I do it manually, not by codes, thanks for your correction

Comment: This is what I want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIUIC,  use

**Option 1]** Numpy `flatten` and `split`

```
In [2535]: collections.Counter([y for x in df.values.flatten() for y in x.split()])
Out[2535]:
Counter({'3': 2,
         'Anak': 2,
         'Cap': 2,
         'Indomie': 4,
         'Mas': 2,
         'Mi': 2,
         'Mie': 2,
         'Noodle': 10,
         'Pop': 2,
         'Telor': 2})
```

**Option 2]**
Use `value_counts()`

```
In [2536]: pd.Series([y for x in df.values.flatten() for y in x.split()]).value_counts()
Out[2536]:
Noodle     10
Indomie     4
Mie         2
Pop         2
Anak        2
Mi          2
Cap         2
Telor       2
Mas         2
3           2
dtype: int64
```

**Options 3]**
Use `stack` and `value_counts`

```
In [2582]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(expand=True).stack()).stack().value_counts()
Out[2582]:
Noodle     10
Indomie     4
Mie         2
Pop         2
Anak        2
Mi          2
Cap         2
Telor       2
Mas         2
3           2
dtype: int64
```

---

Details

```
In [2516]: df
Out[2516]:
   CATEGORY           BRAND
0    Noodle        Anak Mas
1    Noodle        Anak Mas
2    Noodle         Indomie
3    Noodle         Indomie
4    Noodle         Indomie
23   Noodle         Indomie
24   Noodle  Mi Telor Cap 3
25   Noodle  Mi Telor Cap 3
26   Noodle         Pop Mie
27   Noodle         Pop Mie
```

Comment: I prefer to use second solution, because easier to format pandas series to any pandas format

Comment: Option 2 is also faster then option 3