# Trying to create a bag of words of Panda's df

Tags: python, pandas, bag

I am new to pandas (and somewhat new to Python) and am trying to create a bag of words for every row of a specific column. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360435/how-to-create-a-bag-of-words-from-a-pandas-dataframe) is where I took the code from and what follows is my attempt:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cell = df.Review2.iloc[index]
    df['BOW'].iloc[index] = pd.Series([y for x in cell for y in x.split()]).value_counts()
```

This is a single cell from my dataframe on which i'd like to perform the above operation (thus without the for loop for iterating on all the rows):

> problem price say discount 6 bottle even show reduce check changesfive
>   star taste goodthis get best cabinet ever great crisp get best cabinet
>   ever great crisp originally buy three bottle wind buy whole case
>   holidaysnice california cab cab fantastic pleasantly surprise great
>   fullbodied flavor 1 cent ship promotion decent

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame({'review': ['Hello World Hello', 'Hi Bye Bye Bye']})
df['BOW'] = df.review.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(" ")))


              review                         BOW
0  Hello World Hello  {u'World': 1, u'Hello': 2}
1     Hi Bye Bye Bye       {u'Bye': 3, u'Hi': 1}
```

I used pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to process all the rows without iterating them explicitly.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `lambda`: `df.review.str.split().apply(Counter)`.