# Creating bag of words from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360435/how-to-create-a-bag-of-words-from-a-pandas-dataframe) but the output I am looking for is different.

I have a dataframe which lists all the words (columns) and the number they occur for each document (rows).

It looks like this:

```
{'orange': {0: '1',
1: '3'},
'blue': {0: '0',
1: '2'}}
```

The output should "re-create" the original document as a bag of words in this way:

```
corpus = [
['orange'],
['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'blue', 'blue']]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a dataframe at the end, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
data = {'orange': {0: '1',
                   1: '3'},
        'blue': {0: '0',
                 1: '2'}}


results = defaultdict(list)
for color, placement in data.items():
    for row, count in placement.items():
        values = results[row]
        values.extend(int(count) * [color])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results, orient='index')
```

if you want a list of list just do:

```
[v for row, v in results.items()]
```

instead of the `df` build